# Assigning variables to pulled data c++

Tags: c++, coordinates

Basically what I'm trying to do is take coordinate data from a txt file and assign variables to them so I can later calculate distances between those coordinates and a set location (whose data is constant). The txt file looks something like this:

- City1 45 21
- City2 61
- City3 88 25 etc.

Each row is a set of coordinates with a space between x and y. I need to store each x and y variable separately. I have no clue how to do this, as I'm just getting started with c++. If it helps, the txt file is named "CoordinateData.txt."
Any help would be much appreciated.
this is the code I have at the moment but it doesn't seem to work in the way I need it to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
   ifstream inputFile("coordinates.txt");
   string line;

   while (getline(inputFile, line))
   {
      istringstream ss(line);

      string name;
      int var1, var2;

      ss >> name >> var1 >> var2 ;
   }  
}
```

Comment: Please show your code even if it's not working...

Comment: Sorry this is what I have done but I can't seem to get it to work in the way i want it to
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile("coordinates.txt");
    string line;

    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        istringstream ss(line);

        string name;
        int var1, var2;

        ss >> name >> var1 >> var2 ;
    }
}

Comment: Please put it in your question, use {} button to format as code

Comment: I gave it a go sorry about the formatting

Comment: Great, what is the output you get with that program and what is the expected one?

Comment: I get an output that is expected from the code so if I output it, it will display all of the coordinates. What I want to do, which I can't seem to edit the code to do is get it to store the individual x and y coordinates within different variables so then I can use them individual later on in the program

Comment: Is there really a name associated with each coordinate in your data file?  That is a lot of names (I'm still trying to figure out why each coordinate would have a name).

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot to add that in for example city x y

Comment: Your data is not correct.  The *x y* implies that each row contains 2 values.  Some rows have 1, others have more than 2.

Comment: I recommend a `std::map` of a `std::vector` of integers:  `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need arrays, check definition of name, var1 and var2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
   ifstream inputFile("coordinates.txt");
   string line;

   string name[100];
   int var1[100], var2[100];
   int currentLineNumber = 0;

   // It would be better: (getline(inputFile,line) && currentLineNumber < 100)

   while (getline(inputFile, line))
   {
      istringstream ss(line);



      ss >> name[currentLineNumber] >> var1[currentLineNumber] >> var2[currentLineNumber] ;
      currentLineNumber = currentLineNumber + 1;
   }  
}
```

You could iterate the data you got from the file like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < currentLineNumber; ++i) {
    cout << name[i] << "," << var1[i] << "," << var2[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: please after "while" loop ends it would be a good idea to make something like: totalLines = currentLine, and change the last for to use totalLines instead of currentLineNumber. I tried not to change so much in your code. Good luck!

Comment: And don't forget to accept the answer if it is good for you (clicking the check mark at its left)